# Open one div at a time and close all others which are opened in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, show-hide

Trying to implement a show/hide description box.

If the user clicks on the first showDesc link it opens it's description box. Then if the user clicks the second showDesc link it opens it's description box and should close all the others which are opened in VueJs.

I tried something as show below.

[image]

Below is my code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    Show: false
  },
  methods: {
  showDesc: function() {
      this.Show = !this.Show;
   }
  }
})
```

```css
.descContainer {
  position: relative;
  padding: 24px 40px 24px 24px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  display: none;
  line-height: 24px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
}

.descContainer.show {
  position: relative;
  padding: 24px 40px 24px 24px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  display: block;
  line-height: 24px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
}

a.mainSmooth.showDesc {
    color: dodgerblue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main id="app">
  <section>
    <article class="feedBox mainSmooth">
      <div class="feedContainer">
        <div class="feedContent">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <div class="feedButtonContainer"></div>
          <ul class="list-inline feedExtras">
            <li class="">
              <a @click="showDesc" class="mainSmooth showDesc">show description</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div :class="{ show: Show }" class="descContainer">
        <div>Description Text</div>
      </div>
    </article>
    <br/>
    <article class="feedBox mainSmooth">
      <div class="feedContainer">
        <div class="feedContent">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <div class="feedButtonContainer"></div>
          <ul class="list-inline feedExtras">
            <li class="">
           <a @click="showDesc" class="mainSmooth showDesc">show description</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div :class="{ show: Show }" class="descContainer">
        <div>Description Text</div>
      </div>
    </article>
    <br/>
    <article class="feedBox mainSmooth">
      <div class="feedContainer">
        <div class="feedContent">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <div class="feedButtonContainer"></div>
          <ul class="list-inline feedExtras">
            <li class="">
              <a @click="showDesc" class="mainSmooth showDesc">show description</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div :class="{ show: Show }" class="descContainer">
        <div>Description Text</div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about in this way:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  },
  methods: {
  showDesc: function(e) { 
        let allA = document.querySelectorAll("a");
        for(let a of allA) {
         let descContainer = a.closest("article").querySelector("div.descContainer");
          descContainer.classList.remove('show');
          
         if(a === e.target) {
           descContainer.classList.add('show');
          } 
        }
   }
  }
})
```

```css
.descContainer {
  position: relative;
  padding: 24px 40px 24px 24px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  display: none;
  line-height: 24px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
}

.descContainer.show {
  position: relative;
  padding: 24px 40px 24px 24px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  display: block;
  line-height: 24px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
}

a.mainSmooth.showDesc {
    color: dodgerblue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<main id="app">
  <section>
    <article class="feedBox mainSmooth">
      <div class="feedContainer">
        <div class="feedContent">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <div class="feedButtonContainer"></div>
          <ul class="list-inline feedExtras">
            <li class="">
              <a @click="showDesc" class="mainSmooth showDesc">show description</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="descContainer">
        <div>Description Text 1</div>
      </div>
    </article>
    <br/>
    <article class="feedBox mainSmooth">
      <div class="feedContainer">
        <div class="feedContent">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <div class="feedButtonContainer"></div>
          <ul class="list-inline feedExtras">
            <li class="">
              <a @click="showDesc" class="mainSmooth showDesc">show description</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="descContainer">
        <div>Description Text 2</div>
      </div>
    </article>
        <br/>
    <article class="feedBox mainSmooth">
      <div class="feedContainer">
        <div class="feedContent">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <div class="feedButtonContainer"></div>
          <ul class="list-inline feedExtras">
            <li class="">
              <a @click="showDesc" class="mainSmooth showDesc">show description</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="descContainer">
        <div>Description Text 3</div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/26344/).

It's just a raw idea of how it can be done. I hope it helps.

Comment: It would a long list of articles not just two so I cannot use Ids on it. It would be a dynamice list.

Comment: @KamleshKatpara You have to distinguish each `a` from others, if you don't do it, there's no way to follow the MVVM that Vue is based on. Of course, you could recover all `a` using JS and hide them, and after that, show the one in the `e.target` property, but that would unsynchronize anything you put inside `data` property. I just can come up with the idea of generating the `ids` dynamically.

Comment: can you share an example or a plnkr without using ids.
I tried it in jquery:
`$(".showDesc").click(function() {
  var $target = $(this).closest('.feedContainer').next(".descContainer").toggleClass("show");
  $(".descContainer").not($target).removeClass('show'); // hide other open elements
});`

Comment: @KamleshKatpara Here you have the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/26797/) updated. Done without `ids`. Please, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Nope its not working as expected, Once you click on first show description link it opens the desc div, When we click on the second show description link it show close the div which is already open and than open its own div.

Comment: @KamleshKatpara I supposed it was the expected behavior. So should it be only one active? Here's the [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/26895/). In any case, you have the idea already, you can modify it yourself to suit your needs. I answered your question already.